# Having trouble with not adding already saved records in Android SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working on an app that reads the contact names from the mobile and examines whether the name is already saved in a database. If it is already saved to the db, then I just update a saved counter variable but if it isn't then I go on adding it. AT LEAST THIS IS MY INTENTION.

Part of the code is as follows :

```
 public Integer countRecords(String name) {
       SQLiteDatabase db = events.getReadableDatabase();
       Cursor mCount= db.rawQuery("select count('"+CONTACT_NAME+"') from'"+ TABLE_NAME + "' where '" + CONTACT_NAME + "' = '" + name + "'", null); 
       mCount.moveToFirst();
       Integer count= mCount.getInt(0); 
       startManagingCursor(mCount);
       return count;
   }
```

and at the main body of the code goes as follows:

```
 ContentResolver cr= getContentResolver();
        Cursor cu= cr.query(URI, null, null, null, null);
            if(cu.getCount()>0){    
                while(cu.moveToNext()){
                    contactName=cu.getString(cu.getColumnIndex(DNAME));
                    Integer rawValue = countRecords(contactName);
                    if(rawValue==0){
                        addRecord(contactName);
                        addedCounter+=1;
                        recordName=cu.getString(cu.getColumnIndex(DNAME));
                        recordInfo = addedCounter + " " + recordName + "\n";    
                        recordsList+= recordInfo;
                        }
                    else{
                        savedCounter+=1;
                    }
                }
```

Now, I have tried everything I know. The problem seems to be the returning value of the procedure `countRecords`. Maybe I don't use the right criteria in the IF clause `if(rawValue==0){`, because it either adds all contacts, even they are already saved in the db or it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current implementation is not only wrong... it's also *incredibly* inefficient. Try something like this instead:

```
// use as the 2nd argument; otherwise, the cursor will return all information
// associated with the contacts. this is inefficient because you only care
// about the column DNAME in the while loop.
final String[] PROJECTION_CONTACTS = new String[] { DNAME };
final String[] PROJECTION_DATABASE = new String[] { CONTACT_NAME };

// you only need to retrieve this once (dont do it inside the loop)
SQLiteDatabase db = events.getReadableDatabase();

Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(URI, PROJECTION_CONTACTS, null, null, null);

if (c.moveToFirst()) { 
    // then the cursor is not empty

    // compute the columnIndex for "DNAME" only once
    final int col = c.getColumnIndex(DNAME);

    while(c.moveToNext()) {
        // iterate each 
        contactName = c.getString(col);
        Cursor exist = db.query(TABLE_NAME, 
                                PROJECTION_DATABASE, 
                                CONTACT_NAME + " = ?",
                                new String[] { contactName }, 
                                null);

        if (exist.moveToFirst()) {
            // the cursor is not empty, so it exists in the database
        } else {
            // the cursor is empty, so it doesn't exist in the database
        }
        exist.close();
    }
}
c.close();
```

Something like this should work. (I guarantee you I made a typo somewhere, but the general idea of it should get you started). Please please please make sure you do this asynchronously on a separate thread... it could potentially be a very time consuming operation.

Comment: Ok Alex you are a genius no doubt about that!!!! One thing is missing before kneeling in front of you......

Comment: The method query(String, String[], String, String[], String, String, String) in the type SQLiteDatabase is not applicable for the arguments (String, 
 String[], String, String[], null) what's missing from this query ????

Comment: oops... you can probably get away with using any of the `query` methods, for example [**this one**](http://tinyurl.com/4hgmrlt).

Comment: did the general idea of it make sense? because I'm not sure if exactly what i wrote down is right lol... i got confused a tiny bit because i'm not familiar with your database structure.

Comment: @APOSTOLOS, also remember `c.close()` at the very end.

Comment: Alex you are really the best. It worked perfectly although i had to change the if (c.moveToFirst())  to if(cu.getCount()>0){ because it skipped the first contact.

Comment: I really want to express you my utmost gratitude for all the advice you gave me because it's not just i you helped me solve this problem i was facing a couple of days now (which you know, you were there), but mostly because as i told you before, it's my first attempts and you taught me thing university teachers haven't. So thanks!!!!!!!

Comment: haha, it becomes easier to see these things with experience :). no problem. by the way, you should [**accept the answer**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) and upvote the helpful answers if your problem is solved now :).

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
Cursor mCount= db.rawQuery("select count("+CONTACT_NAME+") from "+ TABLE_NAME + " where " + CONTACT_NAME + " = '" + name + "'", null);
```

You have an additional single quotes between column names.

Answer (score 0):

A bit simple form of your desired query:

```
Cursor mCount= db.rawQuery("select count(1) from "+ TABLE_NAME + 
" where " + CONTACT_NAME + " = '" + name + "'", null);
```